# Admin Main Content hidden

Tags: control-panel

Installing Craft 2.2 succeeded. But every main content in the admin is hidden. Example Dashboard (copy & paste from ff debug, which shows only containers without sub nodes!):

```
<main id="main" role="main">
    <div class="grid" style="">
    <div class="resize-triggers">
    <div class="item first" data-colspan="1"> <---- display: none
    <div class="item" data-colspan="1"> <---- display: none
    <div class="item" data-colspan="1"> <---- display: none
    <div class="item" data-colspan="1"> <---- display: none
    <div class="item" data-colspan="1"> <---- display: none
</main>
```

When display: none is disabled in FireDebug I see evreything how it should.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a browser bug. Dashboard is not working with Firefox 20. With Firefox 31 admin is working.

Comment: Strange. Glad updating Firefox worked though!